# WPF Prism Request Navigate activation error

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Referring the StockTraderRI, I created a popup region in my shell

```
infBehaviors:RegionPopupBehaviors.CreatePopupRegionWithName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SecondaryRegion}"
```

In the module I am trying to load the view to the popup

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.SecondaryRegion, new Uri("/OrderDetailsView", UriKind.Relative));
```

OrderDetailsView is a view within OrderDetailsModule. At this point I am getting the below error

```
Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Object, key "OrderDetailsView"
```

Stack trace looks like below

```
 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103
   at Prism.Regions.RegionNavigationContentLoader.CreateNewRegionItem(String candidateTargetContract)
```

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register your objects for navigation.  If you are using Prism 6 you must use `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<OrderDetailsView>();`

If using v5 or less you must use `container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(OrderDetailsView), "OrderDetailsView");`

EDIT: If using MEF, you must provide the view name in the Export Attribute:

```
[Export("OrderDetailsView")]
public class OrderDetailsView : UserControl
{ ... }
```

Comment: I am using MEF and Prism 6. So the export attribute on my view should have taken care of the registration? I don't see the RegisterTypeForNavigation/RegisterType ("OrderDetailsView") used anywhere in the StockTraderRI either.

Comment: Ahh MEF.... In that case are you attributing your view with the [Export("OrderDetailsView")] attribute?  See docs: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/60-Navigation.md#basic-region-navigation